# How to connect a dynamic countdown timer to MySQL properly using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timer, connection, countdown

Hello So my question relates to two questions, first the timer works properly except when refreshing the

> index.php

page which is the page that the timer displays, the timer restarts over, So I want to fix that, and this was my first question, second is I want when the timer finishes or gets to 00:00:00 then I want Something to happen for example like alerts, here is the pages that refers to the dynamic countdown timer,

**response.php**

```
 <?php 
session_start();
$from_time1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time1 = $_SESSION["end_time"];
$timefirst=strtotime($from_time1);
$timesecond = strtotime($to_time1);
$differenceinseconds = $timesecond - $timefirst;
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $differenceinseconds);
?>
```

**first.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($link, "test");

$duration = "";
$res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from timer");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $duration = $row['duration'];
   
}
$_SESSION["duration"] = $duration;
$_SESSION["start_time"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


 $end_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$_SESSION["duration"].'minutes', strtotime($_SESSION["start_time"])));


$_SESSION["end_time"] = $end_time;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location="index.php";

</script>
?>
```

**index.php**

```
  <div id="response"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    setInterval(function()
    {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "response.php", false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   
   
   
    }, 1000);


    </script>
```

**timer table**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.7
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:anon
-- Generation Time: Oct 02, 2022 at 10:27 PM
-- Server version: 10.2.44-MariaDB-cll-lve
-- PHP Version: 7.4.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `timer`
--

CREATE TABLE `timer` (
  `duration` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `timer`
--
ALTER TABLE `timer`
 

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `timer`
--
ALTER TABLE `timer`
 

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

I know the way I described my question is kinda weird, Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code.

Comment: Why are you loading every record in the table, but only fetching one value? Maybe you need `LIMIT 1`, and probably with some kind of `ORDER BY` to pick the right one first.

Comment: It's also not clear what "duration" is supposed to be when it's a `VARCHAR(50)`. Why not store the target time as a `DATETIME` and count down to that?

Comment: This is honestly probably better suited for JavaScript. The client-server paradigm of HTTP along with static HTML doesn’t really lend itself to “something happening”. PHP could deliver to  JS (via AJAX or HTML) a timestamp (or similar) and JS could set a timer to then “do something”, including counting down if you want.